# MSVC13RC still not respecting C standards?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I just downloaded the MSVC2013RC as I heared it will be treating the c standard much better then the previous versions of MSVC did. So I just downloaded it and tested some stuff I was really looking for on windows platform.

But already the first test dissapointed me pretty much.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int testFunction(int iIn);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int *TheKiddingBool;

    TheKiddingBool= NULL;

    TheKiddingBool= malloc(sizeof (int));

    *TheKiddingBool= 17;

    _Bool bWow;

    bWow = true;

    if (testFunction(*TheKiddingBool) == bWow)
    {
        printf("\r\nQAtest succesed!\r\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int testFunction(int iIn)
{
    return iIn;
}
```

The comparison of `testFunction(*TheKiddingBool) == bWow` returns false.
Is this a pretty hard bug in The C compiler of MSVC13?

or do I just understand the line

> 6.3.1.2 Boolean type
>
> §1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares           equal
> to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

of the c99 ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 pretty wrong?

Comment: When comparing `int` with `_Bool`, is the `int` converted to `_Bool` or is the `_Bool` converted to `int`?

Comment: Hm interesting question, but shouldn't a smart compiler notice that it is senseless to convert `int` to `_Bool` if I comapre `int` with `_Bool`?

Comment: 6.3.1.1 — The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.

Comment: @msam What does this mean?

Comment: @Zaibis `bWow` gets casted to int. Make the function return _Bool or cast the return value.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the irony positively dripping that MS is releasing a compiler that is "more" inline with *the standard*? Only 14 years later and they're *almost* there. woot?

Comment: Hmm, this somehow seems to be a real pitfall! I believe this low ranking of _Bool will cause a lot of bugs...

Comment: @RedX I think so too, but the point is, this isn't microsofts fault, as the standard says It HAS to have the lwoest ranking.

Comment: @Zaibis you can of course also simply write `if (testFunction(*TheKiddingBool))`

Comment: @msam yeah ofc. i can, but I jsut wanted to explicitly experimetn with this conversion, as i thought the ranking is to understand in the other way arround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 6.3.1.1 — The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.

This means that `_Bool` will be implicitly converted to the respective integer type when an arithmetic comparison is performed.

Note that taking into consideration

> 6.3 Conversion of an operand value to a compatible type causes no change to the value or the
>   representation.

and

> 6.2.5 An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1.

`_Bool` has to have lower rank than other integers, since converting an 8+ bit integer to a potentially 1-bit-represented bool would amount to truncation, and a change in the value/representation

Answer (score 3):

**According to 7.18.3**

**true**

which expands to the integer constant 1

makes your comparison as  `if (17 == 1)` which returns `false`.

Comment: You are right but the point i was confusing with was, why is it clear that true will be converted to 1 and not 17 to true?;) .... Now i know it ofc. But before that was the bottleneck.

Comment: @Zaibis because 17 is int and true is _Bool. AFAIK

Comment: yeah that is true but the point why this happens is that the standard gives bool the smallest ranking of all itneger types, and the standard  says if 2 not fitting integere types get operated on, then the one with less rankign gets converted to the one with higher ranking (and that was, what I didn't knew before)

Answer (score 2):

Well as msam pointed me to

> 6.3.1.1 — The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.

And I looked up what this "ranking" means, I figgured out, This isn't a bug, I just used the wrong return type, as the standard says _Bool has to have the lowest ranking.

(Here again thanks for the help)